# Problem with clone stamp tool not sampling correctly

Tags: lightroom, photoshop

Photoshop CC 2015.1.2 release

[image]

I'm trying to clone out this plug socket but the clone stamp tool seems to either lighten or darken when painting the sample in. It results in a patchy job. I've reset the clone stamp tool numerous times and it's had no effect. Doesn't change when I sample from all layers, current layer or current and below.

I thought it could be my eyes playing tricks on me, but I don't think it is.
I can get a much better result in Lightroom using the spot removal tool, sampling without much thought.

*Below – Trying to remove it in photoshop: I sampled close by, trying to match as closely as I could. The samples are all over the place, producing colours that don't exist anywhere near (if at all) where I sampled from.*

[image]

Using the spot removal tool in Lightroom: A really quick and dirty attempt, cloning from fairly random areas gives much better results, albeit not as good as I can usually get with the clone tool. Unfortunately I can't link an image as I have no rep points. However, it looks almost perfect.

I've never had this problem before, it seems to have happened in the last few days. Any ideas? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no "Problem", you are cloning a lighter area!

You need to revise your technique...

You are trying to clone within a gradient, You need to clone in a similarly graded area such as the left-side. TBH cloning to erase an artefact within a gradient is one of the harder tasks in image manipulation to get to look any good.

[image]

Comment: Ah I'm an idiot. Thanks for the response. I seem to be getting a much better result with the patch tool. It manages to match the gradients quite well, similar to how it does it in lightroom.

Answer (score -2):

Its  seems like a software issue, some cc versions will clone only certain channels for some reason

Some times you have to upgrade to a new/old version to solve this.